# OpenAM SAML2 Transient Federation and Persistent Federation

Tags: saml, persistent, openam, transient

Is it applicable to configure OpenAM service provider to support both SAML2 Transient federation and persistent federation at the same time from different IDP and how can we configure this?

(Note: now we did not store user identity in SP)

Also is it applicable to map different SAML Assertion Attribute in SAML response Coming from different IDP to the same attribute in OpenAM service provider if we implemented both SAML2 Transient federation and persistent.

example :
if IDP1 send the "user email" like “UserEmail”
and IDP2 send "user email" like “email”

how we can map this in our service provider.

Note : openAM version 13.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it applicable to configure OpenAM service provider to support both SAML2 Transient federation and persistent federation at the same time from different IDP

Yes this is possible.

> how can we configure this?

It may depend on the version of OpenAM you are using, hence please provide the OpenAM version and which fork you are using as there are several OpenAM forks.

> Also is it applicable to map different SAML Assertion Attribute in SAML response Coming from different IDP to the same attribute in OpenAM service provider if we implemented both SAML2 Transient federation and persistent.

Yes, you can configure both mappings in Attribute Map of hosted SP (Assertion Processing tab in OpenAM console). It does not depend on the NameID format being used.

Comment: openAM Version 13.0.0  @Bernhard Thalmayr

Comment: could you please how can we implemented both SAML2 Transient federation and persistent.  @Bernhard Thalmayr

Comment: Are you aware about the intended use of NameID format transient and NameID format persistent... (SSO vs. account linking)? Where are you struggling?

Comment: yes, I know that transient federation map all SSO authenticated user to anonymous user in OpenAM LDAP.

And the persistent federation map each user in IDP to an existing user in SP

and if we enable the auto-federation, the user will be created automatically after SSO authentication. @Bernhard Thalmayr

Comment: currently, we use transient federation. and I want to know the suitable way to enable the persistent federation and if we enable the persistent federation this will affects the current transient federation , and if there is any drawback for this use case.@Bernhard Thalmayr

Comment: You can use NameID format persistent and NameID format transient just fine in parallel and I'm not aware of any drawback.

Comment: You may remove your answer below and instead edit your question to provide the OpenAM version being used.